# Correct way to access config files for DBI connection from CGI script Perl

Tags: mysql, perl, cgi, dbi

Hi I am relativley new to Perl and DBI programming, and just started learning CGI. I want to access a Mysql databases via a perl cgi script but I dont want to store the configuration variables (username , password etc ) in the actual script in the cgi-bin. I can use a `require '/path/to/configfile.pl'` statement but only without using `use strict`, which I dont like. 
  I am hoping someone can tell me what is the correct and safe way for including
config files in this specific situation.

Comment: See [this PerlMonks thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=519337).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mysql,then this will work:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:mysql_read_default_file=$config_file;mysql_read_default_group=$group",undef,undef,{});
```

And the config file should be like this:

```
[group_name]
database=my_db
host=X.X.X.X
user=my_user
password=my_password
port=XXXX
[another_group]
...
```